# ArcPy script doesn't work for TRIM function

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, field-mapping, vb

I have this code:

```
import arcpy
import os

def massiveTrim (vrb):
    y=r"shape path"
    for i in y:
        campos = arcpy.ListFields(vrb, "", "String" )
        for camp in campos:
            espacio = "Trim( ["+str(camp.name)+"] )"
            arcpy.CalculateField_management(vrb, str(camp.name), espacio, "VB", "")

print "Finish process"
```

The script use the TRIM function for delete before and after spaces in a text string for all fields in a shape or FC, this task is automatic, the problem is that TRIM doesn't work.
I have ArcGIS 10.5, Pyscripter

Comment: You've misrepresented the problem here. It's not *ArcPy* that isn't honoring a trim, it's the scripting engine of the (unspecified) database target of `CalculateField`. Since you've hidden what the `vrb` variable represents, you now need to provide it in the question.

Comment: No such function in Python?

Comment: Use listfields, da.UpdateCursor and [strip](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp). Not calculate field

Comment: hi, if I delete function def massiveTrim (vbr) the script calculate the fields of the feature and TRIM, but very slowly, with VB in line arcpy.CalculateField_management(vrb, str(camp.name), espacio, "VB", "") it define visual basic parser.

Comment: @FelixIP it define in expression_type (parser) with VB, in function arcpy.CalculateField_management

Answer (score 1):

Use listfields, da.UpdateCursor and [strip](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp).

```
import arcpy
y=r"shape path"
fieldlist= [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(y, "", "String" )]
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(y,fieldlist) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row = [val.strip() for val in row]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```